# How do you find the detailed status of emails on Civimail bounce processing?

Tags: civimail, bounce, bounce-processing

Is there a report somewhere that will tell me how many bounces have occurred of a particular type for an email? So for example, I want to see if johnqpublic@gmail.com has 2 "Syntax" type bounces, so if one more comes in this email will be put on-hold (because the threshold for this type is set to 3 by default). Or if not a report, some pointers toward a DB query that would get at the same data would be very helpful. ATM this process seems a bit of a black box, since I can't see what it is doing or why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bounce Report https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/report/instance/30?reset=1&output=criteria lets you add Bounce Reason in the columns and as a Filter. Perhaps that is what you are after. Otherwise I expect SearchKit now provides a more tweakable approach

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this was missing and added something to fill the gap in 5.65, but I now notice it is broken. Something must have gone wrong in the process — I will look into it and fix it.

If you click the little list icon beside the on hold date on the contact summary, you are supposed to get a list of the bounces for that email.